# Erro de compilação quando envia para terceiros verificar

Tags: java

Estou praticando Java no SPOJ e veio um exercício simples:

> Continua digitando um número e quando 42 aparecer, pare de printar.

E assim fiz tranquilo aqui no meu PC compilando do jeito esperado. O problema é que quando vou submeter ao SPOJ a solução ele sempre dá erro de compilação com os dizeres:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu não sei mais o que fazer para que aceite o código.

Vou deixar aqui o código fonte que eu fiz e o enunciado do problema.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int valor[] = new int[5];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            valor[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

            if (valor[i] >= 100){

                Scanner ln = new Scanner(System.in);
                valor[i] = Integer.parseInt(ln.nextLine());
            }       
        }

        i = 0;
        while(valor[i] != 42){
            System.out.println(valor[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aproveita que fez no ideone e põe o *link* aí.

Comment: Foi mal hehe, aqui o link: http://ideone.com/0DyF7F

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode iniciar um novo `Scanner` a cada passada no laço. Então eu tirei sua criação do laço. Também mandei ler o `Int` ao invés de converter, acho que fica melhor, mas pode voltar ao que era se desejar. Também tive que arrumar a condição do `while` final que estourava o limite do *array*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int valor[] = new int[5];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
            valor[i] = in.nextInt();
            if (valor[i] >= 100) valor[i] = valor[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < valor.length &&valor[i] != 42; i++) System.out.println(valor[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/fhmmnr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ijatascr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/GetData.java).

O código tem erros de lógica mas não é o foco da pergunta. Por exemplo, se a pessoa digitar um valor inválido na segunda vez, ele passa. O código tem problemas de estilo de codificação que não afetam o resultado final. Fica a dica.

Answer (score 1):

O problema desses sites, como o SPOJ e UVA, é que alguns não informam como o input deverá ser feito. Eu já apanhei muito tentando descobrir uma solução para problema de input no UVA até que, enfim, depois de ter que assumir algumas coisas e, também, encontrar um modelo de código em um dos sites, eu consegui.

Primeiro você tem que assumir que não é um usuário quem está rodando o seu programa e, sim, uma máquina.

Essa máquina vai pegar um arquivo txt com valores abirtrários e rodar o seu programa com o arquivo txt de entrada. É o mesmo que você executar o seu programa pelo terminal com o comando "java Main < input.txt". Você pode fazer isso para testar o seu código.

Você tem que assumir, também, que a cada linha do arquivo txt o seu output terá que ser gerado no mesmo instante. Ou seja, no seu exemplo, no seu programa você tem que ler o número 1 e já gerar o output do número 1 na tela.

Sabendo disso e, com o código adequado, você nunca mais terá problemas de input nos sites desse tipo. Segue o código:

```
import java.io.IOException;

class Main implements Runnable {

  static String ReadLn(int maxLength) {

    byte line[] = new byte[maxLength];
    int length = 0;
    int input = -1;

    try {

      while (length < maxLength) {

        input = System.in.read();

        if ((input < 0) || (input == '\n'))
          break;

        line[length++] += input;

      }

      if ((input < 0) && (length == 0))
        return null;

      return new String(line, 0, length);

    } catch (IOException e) {

      return null;

    }

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Main myWork = new Main();
    myWork.run();

  }

  @Override
  public void run() {

    new myStuff().run();

  }

}

class myStuff implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    // O SEU PROGRAMA AQUI

    int input = 0;

    String linha;

    while((linha = Main.ReadLn(255)) != null && (input =   Integer.parseInt(linha)) != 42) {

      System.out.println(input);

    }

  }

}
```

Perceba que aqui está o programa (tudo que ele deve fazer):

```
class myStuff implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    // O SEU PROGRAMA AQUI

    int input = 0;

    String linha;

      while((linha = Main.ReadLn(255)) != null && (input = Integer.parseInt(linha)) != 42) {

        System.out.println(input);

    }

  }

}
```

Essa parte diz para ler até o final do arquivo texto ou até encontrar o número 42:

```
while((linha = Main.ReadLn(255)) != null && (input = Integer.parseInt(linha)) != 42)
```

E é isso! Espero que dê tudo certo! Espero que eu tenha ajudado! Qualquer dúvida só falar!

Comment: Então, essa classe Main vai fazer com que todos os programas que eu fizer (usando essa estrutura) vão funcionar ou essa solução é somente para esse problema?

Comment: Todos os programas

Comment: Muito orbigado! :D